# WiFi is "saved secured" but won't conenct

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

This only happens with one particular network (my device (Samsung galaxy s4, on 5.01) connects to other networks fine), but I know the issue is on my end because other devices connect. My device connected to this network as recently as yesterday, but now it won't.

It shows "WiFi networks available" but when I press connect, nothing at all happens, it doesn't even flicker,still showing "saved,secured" by the network.

It is really strange that my device connects to other networks, and that other devices connect to this network, but I can't. Help?

Comment: Did you try forgetting the network and then connecting to it by adding credentials again?

Comment: Yes, I already did that.

Comment: Already restarted your phone?

Comment: Yes, I did that too

Comment: I have that too with some APs. In `Settings Status` I see one or more IPv6 addresses but no IPv4 address. I get over that with turning off/on WiFi.

Comment: I already tried that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows only "Secured", then it will ask password. But it doesn't ask password because it was already " Saved". Just Forget that WiFi network, turn WiFi off and Turn on & Connect. Enter correct password. Else it doesn't connect. Your problem may be in putting wrong password

Answer (score 0):

Tap on connect, It will show authentication and also shows obtaining ip address. If it does not get ip address you can not connect to Wi-Fi. Resetting network setting and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your problem is because of mismatching frequency between router and device.

Try switching your router's wifi to a 2.4GHz band and then connect with your device. This should work.

Most older devices support only 2.4GHz WiFi. Considering the age of your device, you may have trouble even with a 2.4 GHz channel because of differences within commonly denoted by b/g/n. TBH, I don't know what the big difference is, except that it may not work properly.

Modern devices generally emit a 5 GHz band which is like a zagzillion times faster than 2.4 GHz WiFi. But older devices can't connect to it.

Check your router, there might just be a dual-band option. This means when you try connecting with any device to your wifi, the same name of WiFi will show up, but when you try connecting to it, your device will connect to either 5GHz or the 2.4GHz channel depending on your devices' capabilities and range.

I'm new here so I welcome all constructive criticism from the pros on how I can improve my answers.